# Acer Aspire 5532 failing

Tags: troubleshooting, acer-aspire

My Acer Aspire 5532 (purchased oct. 2009, and dualbooted ubuntu 10.09 and windows 7) began to go to the splash screen and then displays a white screen and starts over every time I turn it on.

I know nothing is wrong with the drive because I use an ubuntu live disk to use my computer

Can anyone please explain these odd happenings?

Comment: How recent is your machine? Did you just purchase it, or is it older?

Comment: We understand the frustration, but it would really help if you would rephrase your question to be more clear on what the actual problem is. For now, it looks more like a complaint than like an actual question, and it will most likely get closed. We understand the anger, but please try to make a clear, objective question anyway. We don't have to feel this frustration.

Comment: Your problem is clearer now, without the rant part, thank you. About your diagnosis, though, using a live disk of Ubuntu doesn't tell you anything about the drive, because it exactly won't use the hard drive. Besides, I would suggest you to give more details on the "splash screen", which screen do you mean? Boot one? Also, when does it go to this screen, what are you doing when it happens? The more details you give, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess would be: try to reinstall Windows and see if that fixes your problem. As you state that it has had every problem known to man, it's possible the original installation wasn't good to begin with.

Make sure you download all the drivers anew, since they might be one of the sources of the problem. Given that you don't complain about Ubuntu's performance, it makes me think the problem is only with Windows.

Comment: Another Acer user here! When I got my Aspire 7720G, it too came with bad drivers and problematic windows installation. I immediately deleted restore partition (yes, I know that some inexperienced people will be uncomfortable with this solution!) and installed windows form a disk. No problems since.